# BigQuery not working properly in Firebase Functions

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do a query on BigQuery using Firebase Functions. When I test the query running the function locally or in the BigQuery console it returns correctly. But when I deploy the function to Firebase and make a request, it returns empty: 
`[ [] ]`.

The code I'm using is:

```
functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    const query = "SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNTIF((event_timestamp / 1000) <= (UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 172800000) OR event_name = 'EVENT_A' OR event_name = 'EVENT_B' ) >= 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) UserIsMature FROM `analytics_table` WHERE user_id='" + id + "AND event_name = 'EVENT_A' OR event_name = 'EVENT_B' OR event_name = 'EVENT_C'"

    bigQuery.query(query).then(result => response.send(result))
});
```

The query that is being run for example is: 
`` SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNTIF((event_timestamp / 1000) <= (UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 172800000) OR event_name = 'EVENT_A' OR event_name = 'EVENT_B' ) >= 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) UserIsMature FROM `analytics_table` WHERE user_id='EBtcJEsCHXN' AND event_name = 'EVENT_A' OR event_name = 'EVENT_B' OR event_name = 'EVENT_C' ``

I don't see any problem in code, especially because I have another function that uses the same code, but a different query and it's working as expected.

Any idea on why it's not working?

Comment: You declare `id` but never use it.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @ThiagoNascimento . . . Edit the query and show the query that is actually being run, by printing out `query`.

Comment: Done, just edited with the query

Answer (score 1):

Print out the query.  I'm pretty sure you have multiple errors, both syntactic and logical.  For instance the `WHERE` clause would appear to be:

```
WHERE user_id='1 AND event_name = 'EVENT_A' OR event_name = 'EVENT_B' OR event_name = 'EVENT_C'
```

(the `1` is a plugged in value).

When you probably intend:

```
WHERE user_id = 1 AND event_name IN ('EVENT_A', 'EVENT_B', 'EVENT_C')
```

Similarly, comparing a `COUNTIF()` to milliseconds in a timestamp seems very suspicious.

I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: The query is working as expected when running locally or through the big query console. So it doesn't seem to be a syntax error